# how do I center images in table (html)

Tags: html

I'm basically trying to center 3 images in-between the top of 4

and I need the top 3 images to center on above the bottom 4

```html
<div class="supercenter center" id="menuButtons" style="bottom: -15%;">
        <table>
                <tr class="menuButtonList">
                    <td id="menu_create"><a tabindex="1" href=""><img class="menubutton menu-create" src="../assets/category-create.png" title="Create"></a></td>
                    <td><a tabindex="1" href="./leaderboard"><img class="menubutton menu-leaderboard" src="../assets/category-scores.png" title="Scores"></a></td>
                    <td><a tabindex="1" href="./search/*?type=saved"><img class="menubutton menu-saved" src="../assets/category-saved.png" title="Saved Levels"></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="menuButtonList">
                    <td id="menu_quests"><a tabindex="1" href=""><img class="menubutton menu-quests" src="../assets/category-quests.png" title="Quests"></a></td>
                    <td id="menu_daily"><a tabindex="1" href="./daily"><img class="menubutton menu-daily" src="../assets/category-daily.png" title="Daily Level"></a></td>
                    <td id="menu_weekly"><a tabindex="1" href="./weekly"><img class="menubutton menu-weekly" src="../assets/category-weekly.png" title="Weekly Demon"></a></td>
                    <td><a tabindex="1" href="./gauntlets"><img class="menubutton menu-gauntlets" src="../assets/category-gauntlets.png" title="Gauntlets"></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="menuButtonList">
                    <td id="menu_featured"><a tabindex="1" href="./search/*?type=featured"><img class="menubutton menu-featured" src="../assets/category-featured.png" title="Featured"></a></td>
                    <td><a tabindex="1" href="./search/*?type=hof"><img class="menubutton menu-hof" src="../assets/category-hof.png" title="Hall Of Fame"></a></td>
                    <td><a tabindex="1" href="./mappacks"><img class="menubutton menu-mappacks" src="../assets/category-packs.png" title="Map Packs"></a></td>
                    <td><a tabindex="1" href="./search"><img class="menubutton menu-search" src="../assets/category-search.png" title="Search"></a></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

The css class aren't really touched so don't worry about that.

I tried using a couple AI stuff like copilot or chatgpt which are too stupid and I tried asking people but didn't get a response.

Comment: Your table is invalid. Row one only has 3 cells. The other rows have 4. I think you need to use something other than tables for this layout. Take a look at CSS grid.

Answer (score 2):

**Option One. Add colspans to your existing table:**

Your data isn't really appropriate for [table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics) but to achieve what you want you will have to modify your table rows to have 12 columns (the lowest common multiple of 3 and 4) and set your cells to span multiple columns. Like so:

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
td a {display:inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; background:blue; border-radius:10px; text-align:center;}
td {text-align:right;}
tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type {text-align:right;}
tr:first-of-type td:last-of-type {text-align:left;}
```

```html
<div class="supercenter center" id="menuButtons" style="bottom: -15%;">
  <table>
    <tr class="menuButtonList">
      <td colspan="4" id="menu_create">
        <a tabindex="1" href=""><img class="menubutton menu-create" src="../assets/category-create.png" title="Create"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./leaderboard"><img class="menubutton menu-leaderboard" src="../assets/category-scores.png" title="Scores"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./search/*?type=saved"><img class="menubutton menu-saved" src="../assets/category-saved.png" title="Saved Levels"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="menuButtonList">
      <td colspan="3" id="menu_quests">
        <a tabindex="1" href=""><img class="menubutton menu-quests" src="../assets/category-quests.png" title="Quests"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" id="menu_daily">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./daily"><img class="menubutton menu-daily" src="../assets/category-daily.png" title="Daily Level"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" id="menu_weekly">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./weekly"><img class="menubutton menu-weekly" src="../assets/category-weekly.png" title="Weekly Demon"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./gauntlets"><img class="menubutton menu-gauntlets" src="../assets/category-gauntlets.png" title="Gauntlets"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="menuButtonList">
      <td colspan="3" id="menu_featured">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./search/*?type=featured"><img class="menubutton menu-featured" src="../assets/category-featured.png" title="Featured"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./search/*?type=hof"><img class="menubutton menu-hof" src="../assets/category-hof.png" title="Hall Of Fame"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./mappacks"><img class="menubutton menu-mappacks" src="../assets/category-packs.png" title="Map Packs"></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <a tabindex="1" href="./search"><img class="menubutton menu-search" src="../assets/category-search.png" title="Search"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Option 2. Use Grid or Flexbox instead:**

Both [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout) and [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) can achieve this sort of layout. Here's an example of one way to achieve it using CSS Grid:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5; }
.div2 { grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 9; }
.div3 { grid-area: 1 / 9 / 2 / 13; }
.div4 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4; }
.div5 { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 7; }
.div6 { grid-area: 2 / 7 / 3 / 10; }
.div7 { grid-area: 2 / 10 / 3 / 13; }
.div8 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 4; }
.div9 { grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 7; }
.div10 { grid-area: 3 / 7 / 4 / 10; }
.div11 { grid-area: 3 / 10 / 4 / 13; }

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
  <div class="div6">6</div>
  <div class="div7">7</div>
  <div class="div8">8</div>
  <div class="div9">9</div>
  <div class="div10">10</div>
  <div class="div11">11</div>
</div>
```

**Resources:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox
- https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: On option 1, it does achieve what I sort of want, but I don't want it to be spaced out, I want the top row to look like https://imgur.com/a/Jt7wg2z if possible.

If your wondering, I forked GDBrowser and most of the code is from that just with more sections, this is where the original is from (line 51) https://github.com/GDColon/GDBrowser/blob/master/html/home.html

Comment: @Xytriza You can achieve that with option 1 assuming that all cell content is the same size as per your provided example. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: It somehow made this

https://imgur.com/Jv4FKsf

Comment: If you want to edit the html directly go to https://gdpsbrowser.xytriza.com/

Comment: is there a solution or no?

Comment: @Xytriza I went to your site. It looks good to me. It's not particularly cool to ask for a solution to X then follow it up with "how about y?" Post a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: ...But yes. There is a solution.

Comment: Ok, how would I make the spacing the same as the other stuff while centered though

Comment: @Xytriza The fix to your site is as per solution 1. You need the row:1, col:1 to align right and row:1, col:3 to align left; I think you might be trolling me.

Comment: Im not trolling you, I stated in the original post that I dont know html and somebody removed it before, I gave you the site URL and said I wanted the fixed spacing to match what geometry dash (a game which this mimics the style of), i also gave the original home.html link from GDColon's repo (I forked)

Comment: If I did something wrong please tell me

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use html **FLEX** but for table you  have two ugly solutions:

**1- Nested tables:**

```css
td{margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center}
table{border-collapse:collapse}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="subtable">
                <table style="width:100%" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cell 1</td>
                        <td>Cell 2</td>
                        <td>Cell 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cell 4</td>
                        <td>Cell 5</td>
                        <td>Cell 6</td>
                        <td>Cell 7</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**2- A table with 12 cells (3 and 4 LCM) and use colspan:**

```css
td{text-align:center}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">1</td>
    <td colspan="4">2</td>
    <td colspan="4">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">4</td>
    <td colspan="3">5</td>
    <td colspan="3">6</td>
    <td colspan="3">7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```